# Quantum Fluctuations of the vacuum

Tags: quantum-field-theory, vacuum

In [this video](https://youtu.be/zNVQfWC_evg?t=1328) we see a visualization of quantum fluctuations. What equations underlie this visualization? And how exactly is it related to quantum field theory? And what is the open problem he talks about saying about this visualization?

[image]

Comment: "The simulation of vacuum fluctuations is by [Derek Leinweber](http://www.physics.adelaide.edu.au/theory/staff/leinweber/VisualQCD/QCDvacuum/)".

Comment: I enjoyed watching the video just now!  Though he doesn't explicitly say so, it seems clear to me, given the mention of the $1M prize, that the open problem he refers to is [Yang-Mills existence and mass-gap problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Yang%E2%80%93Mills_existence_and_mass_gap)

Comment: As a pedantic aside, the philosopher side of me takes issue with the assertion that "it's a computer simulation of *absolutely nothing*".

Comment: Just guessing here – I remember this picture, and if I remember correctly, that is a sample configuration which was encountered among other smilar sample configurations in the Metropolis-Hastings simulation of the QCD vacuum.

Answer (score -1):

Simple answer:

1) The basic equation is the Energy-time uncertainty relation: 
$$\Delta E \Delta t >= \bar{h}/2$$

2)The vacuum fluctuations are described by QFT as the zero-point energy fluctuations of various fields. But this video only describe the above equation. you can imagine it as particle-antiparticle pair creation and annihilation processes.

3) The video describes the problem how these quantum fuzziness become apparent on the large scale when we look at the *CMB Map*.